# installing GIT on EMR

Tags: git, elastic-map-reduce

1) I have been told that git comes stock installed on EMR.  Is this true ? I believe not, as I can confirm that "git" is not found in my elastic-mapreduce ssh terminal.  See: https://raw.github.com/gist/3177009/6128554a2668367b72758be74885836e41898923/gistfile1.txt .

2) I need to install git on EMR, but the following line :

hadoop@ip-10-235-11-52:/mnt$ sudo apt-get install git --assume-yes

Results in :

hadoop@ip-10-235-11-52:/mnt$ sudo apt-get install git --assume-yes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Unfortunately, however, git does not run on this EMR instance, even after issueing this command :

hadoop@ip-10-235-11-52:/mnt$ git
-bash: git: command not found
hadoop@ip-10-235-11-52:/mnt$ sudo git
sudo: git: command not found

Comment: Confirmation that git is NOT installed on EMR by default: https://raw.github.com/gist/3177009/6128554a2668367b72758be74885836e41898923/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 8):

Following up on @jayunit100 answer's:

yum install git-core will work for AWS-EMR.

Answer (score 0):

1) Older EMR instances **do not** appear to come with git installed, stock.

2)

apt-get install git should actually be 
apt-get install git-core

Simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Update from @eduardo-barbaro's answer -

```
yum install git-core
```